# ATtiny85 and MLX90614 cannot read temperature data

Tags: attiny, attiny85

I'm trying to read sensor data from an MLX90614 using an ATtiny85 to turn on some LEDs if the temperature is in the corresponding temperature range.

Right now, all my readings are under 0 degrees. I am very new to electronics so I suspect I am doing something wrong.

I am using the Digistump Attiny85 ([this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.openimpulse.com%2Fblog%2Fproducts-page%2Fproduct-category%2Fdigispark-attiny85-development-board%2F&psig=AOvVaw0IZLa-WrCVuz5UF04RK2cz&ust=1634390348862000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjhxqFwoTCPCekfXAzPMCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP)). Currently I have the SCL and SDA ports directly plugged into the SCL/ SDA pins of the Attiny85. But this doesn't seem to work.

Please advise on how to get the Attiny85 to read the sensor data.

Comment: Are you using the sensor on a module? If yes, which module? Are there pull-ups on the I2C bus lines? Do the chips share ground and supply voltage?

Comment: @Justme Yes, sensor on a module I2C MLX90614, [this one](https://www.otronic.nl/a-62368433/sensors/infrarood-thermometer-i2c-mlx90614/?gclid=CjwKCAjwzaSLBhBJEiwAJSRokpS5kWGESg6Mkcq4lgr9Nk0EaAVZNCJ3nsYDrWWCsZrT87Z4EDQ5gRoCcu0QAvD_BwE) I'm not sure exactly what pull-ups are so I cannot answer that question. Yes, the sensor is connected to the ATtiny's ground and 5v pins. Thanks.

Comment: The sensor page says something about 10k resistors but as I don't read Dutch and there are no manual or schematics available I can't say if it already has pull ups or requires you to provide them. When buying stuff, you need to be sure you are given enough information how to use the stuff, so don't buy stuff without instructions. How did you connect it to AVR and what program is it running? We need the details in a way that someone could do exactly what you have done to try figuring out the issue.

Comment: Fair enough. I connected SDA from sensor to pin 0, SCL to pin 2, GND to Attiny85 ground pin and VIN to Attiny85 5V pin. I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/IR-Thermometer/). Just modified to get rid of the Neopixel. I tried the wiring diagram there but I could not get it to work still. I also tried plugging the pins directly to the attiny85.  Code and diagram are at the link.

Comment: What have you debugged in the circuit? Measured any voltages? I have a guess so I don't give it as an answer : The module, even if powered from 5V, seems to have a regulator to bring down voltage to 3V, and thus the I2C bus uses 3V voltage as the 10k pull-ups are connected to 3V. And 3V is at the border of reliably reading as logic high by the ATtiny85 powered at 5V. It is possible that in the tutorial they do not use a MLX module with built-in regulator but a MLX directly.

Comment: I currently do not have access to any voltmeters sadly but the only thing I did do was pull out the sensor board and it had no effect on the attiny. Is there then any solution to get it to work with the attiny? The plan is to later program another attiny and power it off 2 AAA batteries. Maybe when the attiny runs on 3V the sensor board will work too? I'm quite the noob at this so my apologies for any nonsense.

Comment: It might be, but as long as the circuit on the LMX module remains a mystery that needs solving, there is no guaratee how it works. Try reverse engineering the components and connections. The next time you buy something, make sure you know what you are buying. If the seller gave you no schematics, manuals or user guides how to use the component in any way, it is a black box you don't know anything about, so it is useless until you solve how it works yourself (by googling and measuring). Sometimes sellers keep selling unknown stuff if people keep buying it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help.

Comment: You need pull up resistors on your SCL/SDA pins in order for this to work